# Pathfinding in isometric game with autotiles: How to modify NavigationMesh

Tags: path-finding, godot, procedural-generation, isometric, tilesets

Im generating a map proceduraly with isometric autotiles. Each tile has its navigation poligon defined in the Tilemap editor. The Navigationmesh is working fine. The thing is that the map I generate is bigger than the actually playable area. I dont want the human player to see the borders of the map, the "black background". So I'm limiting the camera view movement. Therefore, the navigationmesh goes outside of the playable area, like in this image:

[image: gameview]

I'm using pathfinding to move the player character. Since the map is generated proceduraly, sometimes it generates a map where the path to a point goes outside the playable area an then comes back in order to reach its destination. Like this:

[image: pathfinding]

A player in O would go outside the playable are to reach X. In X could be a point of interest, so if this kind of map is generated, I would simply regenerate it until i get a feasible one.

I'm using GODOT 3.51.

I have think about:

- Carving a hole in the navigation mesh on the borders of the playable area using clip_polygons(). BUT since im using autotile navigation, it is very hard to get the navigationpoligoninstance. I have tried this but failed miserably.

-Adding NavigationObstacles on the borders: Hadn't tried this, but as far as i understand from my research, this will not avoid the agent to generate the path to the destination.

My idea is to achieve that no path goes out of the playable area and then check is the map is feasible by checking if all points of interest (randomly spawned) are reacheable. This is done by cheking the last point of every path to interest points from the starting point an seeing if it is equal to the point of interest position.

I hope this is understandable. Sometimes I dont understand myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to mind is to use two versions of the tiles. One that is not passable which will be used to generate the areas that the players should not be able to reach. And the regular one used for the playable area.

Comment: In fact while i was writing the question, i thought about this solution and already implemented it. I think it is a good walkaround. Thank you!